# How to make reverse relationship for multiple Role in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i`m using Entrust and has 3 types of users (Admin,Moderator, Player);
I have 2 tables: Users and Hall (Game place); 
All this users (Admin, Moderator, Player) are stored in the Users table; 
so Admin and Moderator can make Hall; Users connected with hall_id;

I did relationship in Hall with Users for Owner_Id (who created Hall);

### and i want do same back for Players;

Users: when i did something in migration like $table->foreign('hall_id')->references('id')->on('hall')
 => i have error; 
Of course I do not forget to register unsigned() and hall_id is integer;

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update
>     a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bingo`.`#sql-396_1dc`, CONSTR
>     AINT `users_hall_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`hall_id`) REFERENCES `hall` (`id`
>   )) (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_hall_id_foreign` foreig
>     n key (`hall_id`) references `hall` (`id`))

---

I want get about hall information of Players

Comment: could you post your migration and model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to run the migration with your database empty? if you did and you still having this error try adding a nullable attribute.
`Try adding $table->integer('hall_id')->nullable();`

I hope that helps!